# What is the difference between $(...) and `...`?

Tags: bash

Using GNU bash 4.1.2, I get:

```
[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$ echo `echo '\\'`
\
[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$ echo $(echo '\\')
\\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is documented in `man bash`:

> When  the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
>   retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `, or \.  The
>   first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command
>   substitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between
>   the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

As per `man bash`, a similar difference between the two forms is found if `$` follows the backslash:

```
$ echo `echo 'out: \$'`
out: $
$ echo $(echo 'out: \$')
out: \$
```

And the same if a backtick follows the backslash:

```
$ echo `echo 'out: \`'`
out: `
$ echo $(echo 'out: \`')
out: \`
```

#### Motivation

Since it could be useful to put a backtick as a character inside the command substitution, the backtick form has to have a way to escape a backtick.  To make sure that one can put the escape character whereever one wants, then there also needs to be a way to escape the escape.

Comment: In other words: backquotes have weird quoting/escaping rules, while `$()` parses its contents normally. Also, `$()` is much easier for a human to read. So use `$()`.